# CSS Display separate text on Hover or Click on Image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display a text message when the user hovers or clicks on a image. These messages will be: "Good" or "Great" different text for each image. For some reason I cannot get it to work, I can get it to work if I hovered over plain old text but not on the image. I've been pulling out my hair for 2 days now really need help with this.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css'>

<style>

        @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700");
        
        .rating-wrapper {
          max-width: 400px;
          margin: 80px auto;
          background: #fff;
          padding: 1em;
          border-radius: 3px;
          box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
        .rating-wrapper .rating-label {
          text-align: center;
          font-weight: 700;
          display: block;
        }
        .rating-wrapper .ratingItemList {
          max-width: 300px;
          margin: auto;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: space-between;
          padding: 1em 0;
        }
        .rating-wrapper input.rating {
          display: none;
        }
        .rating-wrapper label.rating {
          padding: 5px 3px;
          font-size: 32px;
          opacity: 0.7;
          filter: grayscale(1);
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        .rating-wrapper label.rating:hover {
          filter: grayscale(0.84);
          transform: scale(1.1);
          transition: 100ms ease;
        }
        .rating-wrapper input.rating:checked + label.rating {
          filter: grayscale(0);
          opacity: 1;
          transform: scale(1.1);
        }
        
        .hide {
          display: none;
        }
            
        .myDIV:hover + .hide {
          display: block;
          color: red;
        }

</style>
```

```html
    <form class="rating-wrapper">
      <label class="rating-label">How helpful was this?
        <div class="ratingItemList">
          
          <input class="rating rating-4" id="rating-4-2" type="radio" value="4" name="rating"/>
          <label class="rating rating-4" for="rating-4-2"><i class="em em-grinning"></i></label>
          
          <input class="rating rating-5" id="rating-5-2" type="radio" value="5" name="rating"/>
          <label class="rating rating-5" for="rating-5-2"><i class="em em-star-struck"></i></label>
        </div>
      </label>
      
      <label class="myDIV">Hover over me.</label>
      
      <div class="hide"><br>I am shown when someone hovers over the image above.</div>
        
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) I don't see any way to do this with CSS only. But it can be done with Javascript.

```js
const divShow = document.querySelector('.hide');
function showUp(){
  
  divShow.style.display = "block";
  divShow.style.color = "red";
}
function hide(){
  divShow.style.display = "none";
  
}
```

```css
  @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700");
        
        .rating-wrapper {
          max-width: 400px;
          margin: 80px auto;
          background: #fff;
          padding: 1em;
          border-radius: 3px;
          box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
        .rating-wrapper .rating-label {
          text-align: center;
          font-weight: 700;
          display: block;
          position: relative;
        }
        .rating-wrapper .ratingItemList {
          max-width: 300px;
          margin: auto;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: space-between;
          padding: 1em 0;
        }
        .rating-wrapper input.rating {
          display: none;
        }
        .rating-wrapper label.rating {
          padding: 5px 3px;
          font-size: 32px;
          opacity: 0.7;
          filter: grayscale(1);
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        .rating-wrapper label.rating:hover {
          filter: grayscale(0.84);
          transform: scale(1.1);
          transition: 100ms ease;
        }
        .rating-wrapper input.rating:checked + label.rating {
          filter: grayscale(0);
          opacity: 1;
          transform: scale(1.1);
        }
        
        .hide {
          display: none;
        }
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css'>
<form class="rating-wrapper">
      <label class="rating-label">How helpful was this?
        <div class="ratingItemList">
          
          <input class="rating rating-4" id="rating-4-2" type="radio" value="4" name="rating"/>
          
          <label onmouseover="showUp()" onmouseleave="hide()"  class="rating rating-4" for="rating-4-2"><i class="em em-grinning"></i>
            
          </label>
         
          
          <input class="rating rating-5" id="rating-5-2" type="radio" value="5" name="rating"/>
          <label onmouseover="showUp()" onmouseleave="hide()" class="rating rating-5" for="rating-5-2"><i class="em em-star-struck"></i></labe>
          
        </div>
      </label>
      
      <label onmouseover="showUp()" onmouseleave="hide()" class="myDIV">Hello world</label>
      <div class="hide"><br>I am shown when someone hovers over the image above.</div>
      
        
    </form>
```